# JQuery btn-widgetbar redirect when user is not logged

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress

I want to run jquery so that the wordpress widget bar button is not displayed when the user is not logged in and instead is redirected to the registration page.

Thanks in advance, I'm a bit stuck with this, I have managed to change the image of the button by css depending on whether it is logged in or not but i cant with the jquery

Comment: what do you mean by 'wordpress widget bar button'?

Comment: Sorry if i dont explain well, it is not my language .. My wordpress theme has a button that displays a sidebar called widgetbar, i changed the icon of this button depending on whether the user is logged or not, but i need that button dont displays the widgetbar when the user is not logged in and instead of this redirects to other wordpress page for register / login.

Comment: I need to see the code responsible for adding this button to be able to give a more specific answer. What theme are you using?

Answer (score 0):

For any element you're trying to display only for logged-in users, you can do this:

```
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { ?>
<!-- content --> //Add here the block of code that displays the widget bar button
<?php } ?>
```

P.S. I thought the task you're trying to achieve is best done with php rather than jquery.

Comment: Hi Sheedo, at first thanks a lot for your answer, maybe i am not explain well before, sorry but its an important project for me and im not an expert. I ask for JQuery because i thought was in there where i can evaluate better the button click event and then if user is not logged redirect to other page instead off the usual behavior, i can do this in php? Thanks again